# How to cancel the parsing of SBJsonStreamParser?

Tags: iphone, ios, sbjson

I use SBJsonStreamParser(class of SBJson) to parse JSON.now I want to know how to cancel parsing of the class when the class is parsing at runtime.I couldn't find such API.someone please help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such API at the moment. If you need it, I suggest raising an issue in [the issue tracker](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/issues). You are also free to implement it yourself, and send a pull request. I will accept the patch if it's any good.

**Disclaimer: I am SBJson's author.**

*Update:* just to let you know, SBJson 4 (released December 2013) supports cancelling.

Comment: Mr. Brautaset,  thank you for getting my app through when we needed you! Nice to know you are on this site. (I've since switched to NSJSONSerialization as I have a mix of legacy code without ARC and code with ARC and this was getting to be a hassle with SBJson but props to you for your contribution!)